# Convert Angular SpaTemplate Core to Core .Net Framework

Tags: asp.net, angularjs, node.js

I am working on converting the SpaTemplate provided by Microsoft. This template is an Angular 2 implementation using Asp.Net Core. Core is fine and all but I could care less about using it and it limits some of my code base. So with that in mind I want to use Angular 2 but I want to use Asp.Net Core with the .Net Framework.

I created the template, then a blank .Net Core w/.Net Framework project.

I have been copying files to the blank project but still cannot get it to run.

Copied:

- wwwroot
- ClientApp
- Controllers
- Views
- package.json
- webpack.config.js
- Startup.cs contents

I get this error when launching my new project:

```
Exception: Call to Node module failed with error: Error: No ResourceLoader implementation has been provided. Can't read the url "app.component.html"
at Object.get (D:\Source\Susquehanna-Software\EarlyScTrackerDemos\NetFrameScTrackerDemo\ClientApp\dist\vendor.js:60768:15)
at DirectiveNormalizer.module.exports.DirectiveNormalizer._fetch (D:\Source\Susquehanna-Software\EarlyScTrackerDemos\NetFrameScTrackerDemo\ClientApp\dist\vendor.js:47872:45)
at DirectiveNormalizer.module.exports.DirectiveNormalizer.normalizeTemplateAsync (D:\Source\Susquehanna-Software\EarlyScTrackerDemos\NetFrameScTrackerDemo\ClientApp\dist\vendor.js:47927:21)
at DirectiveNormalizer.module.exports.DirectiveNormalizer.normalizeTemplate (D:\Source\Susquehanna-Software\EarlyScTrackerDemos\NetFrameScTrackerDemo\ClientApp\dist\vendor.js:47899:44)
at CompileMetadataResolver.module.exports.CompileMetadataResolver._loadDirectiveMetadata (D:\Source\Susquehanna-Software\EarlyScTrackerDemos\NetFrameScTrackerDemo\ClientApp\dist\vendor.js:48830:75)
at D:\Source\Susquehanna-Software\EarlyScTrackerDemos\NetFrameScTrackerDemo\ClientApp\dist\vendor.js:49026:54
at Array.forEach (native)
at CompileMetadataResolver.module.exports.CompileMetadataResolver.loadNgModuleDirectiveAndPipeMetadata (D:\Source\Susquehanna-Software\EarlyScTrackerDemos\NetFrameScTrackerDemo\ClientApp\dist\vendor.js:49025:41)
at D:\Source\Susquehanna-Software\EarlyScTrackerDemos\NetFrameScTrackerDemo\ClientApp\dist\vendor.js:60221:58
at Array.forEach (native)
Microsoft.AspNetCore.NodeServices.HostingModels.HttpNodeInstance+<InvokeExportAsync>d__7.MoveNext()
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution was to generate the .Net Core SpaTemplate, edit csproj to net46, use Nuget to install some packages, and rebuild.